# Simple Symfony2 / Doctrine Validation not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

This just doesn't make sense. I can't seem to get a simple Symfony2 validation working.

```
$insert = new MyEntity();
$insert->setTest1( 'test' );
$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errors = $validator->validate($insert);
```

...but $errors is always an object with an empty constraints array. It never fails the validation.

My configuration (Yaml):

```
MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity:
    properties:
        test1:
            - MinLength: 10
            - Email
    type: entity
    table: null
    fields:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
        test1:
            type: string
            length: 255
            column: test_1
        test2:
            type: integer
            column: test_2
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing doctrine's **mapping** and symfony's **validation** in a single yml file.

The [validation configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#the-basics-of-validation) in yml is loaded from the files:

```
Acme/YourBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml  // YAML

Acme/YourBundle/Resources/config/validation.xml  // XML
```

And the [mapping information](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#add-mapping-information) should be placed in one of:

```
Acme/YourBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/MyEntity.orm.yml  // YAML

Acme/YourBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/MyEntity.orm.xml  // XML

Acme/YourBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/orm/MyEntity.orm.yml // YAML

Acme/YourBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/orm/MyEntity.orm.xml // XML
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I'm also trying to have the validator return an array, something like $errors[0]['message'] = "That is not a valid email address". It always returns an object which is a nightmare to parse into this format.

Comment: This isn't actually form related. I'm just using the code at the top of the page. Is it not possible with the raw validator?